# Why a tfs 2018 deployment group phase will run after previous one partially failed?

Tags: tfs, azure-pipelines

I am a TFS 2018 update 2 user. I use release management as my CD solution.
I create a release definition consists of multiple deployment group phases.
I execute this release definition, I found one of my deployment group phase partially failed. as the following screenshot shows:
[image]

I think my release definition will stop right after this partially failed deployment group phase, but it doesn't. It runs next deployment group phase(as my screenshot shows). I am sure all of the deployment phases had set "Only when all previous phases have succeeded".

What happened? and anyone had a solution/workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the control option `Continue on error` is **disabled**(uncheck) on the specific failed task.

Based on your screenshot the previous phase is partially **SUCCEEDED** (partially failed).

The systems will continue to run subsequent tasks/phases if the previous tasks/phases is partially SUCCEEDED.

To stop the next phases/tasks, you need to completely fail the previous task/phase (Disable control option `Continue on error`).

[image]

Comment: I think my question is similar to this post: https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/7333

Comment: @KentLu So, have your resolved the issue with workarounds?

Comment: no, I still find a better way to resloved it. And I can not find the excatly date/version 
 when TFS team will solve this bug.